# How to enable directory listing in Apache on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, apache-http-server

I want to transfer files from my Macbook to my iPod by enabling web sharing on the MacBook.

Comment: Just noticed that directory listing on Mac is enabled on Apache by default - I didnt have proper permissions earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is a one-off sharing, you might try the HTTP server built into the Python SimpleHTTPServer module for [exposing a directory tree to the web](http://www.shell-fu.org/lister.php?id=54).

Comment: Yes, this is better - and I guess more secure as I dont have to keep the httpd service on all the time , thnks.

Answer (score 0):

Directory Listing is enabled by default in both `/Library/WebServer/Documents` and your Sites folder in your home folder. However the directory listing will not appear if an index.html is present in that directory.