# Localhost website using Apache on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, apache-http-server, localhost

I am trying to set up a webserver on my Mac so that I can access my folder through http://localhost:8085/test.html.

How do I set this up?

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial should have what you need. See "Solution to #2: Port based virtual hosts":

http://suburbia.org.uk/blog/2007/11/13/120206.html

Answer (score 0):

Just answered this at [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/160567/how-to-enable-directory-listing-in-apache-on-mac-os-x/160573#160573).  If your goal is a one-off sharing, you might try the HTTP server built into the Python SimpleHTTPServer module for [exposing a directory tree to the web](http://www.shell-fu.org/lister.php?id=54).

Comment: Thanks. With this will I be able to access 'localhost' from my applications?

Comment: @Egil Yes, you can. You can even bind to `0.0.0.0`, meaning the folder will be exposed on every interface you have.

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP is one of the most popular packages for localhost servers but the question is...what languages do you want this server to support? Because the .html files can be seen on browsers without any server...XAMPP on the other hand supports Perl and PHP.There are also other servers for different languages...good luck